# Can we infer normality of $x$ and $y$ from normality of $x+y$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

Following are snapshot of Page-`217` and `218` of [Probability, Random Variables, and Stochastic Processes By Athanasios Papoulis, S. Unnikrishna Pillai](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Probability_Random_Variables_and_Stochas/g6eUoWOlcQMC?hl=en&gbpv=0)

> [image]
> [image]

It shows that the normality of $x$ and $y$ can deduce the normality of $ax+by$. However, it post a conclusion that only if $ax+by$ is normal for all $a$ and $b$ can we make sure the normality of $x$ and $y$. But from the formulae in the picture I seems to have the conclusion that we can infer normality of $x$ and $y$ from normality of $x+y$. What's wrong inside this? And I cannot figure out the way to construct a counterexample in the book.

If $x+y$ is normally distributed then `(6-196)` holds for $w_1=w_2=1$ and `(6-195)` follows. Why the characteristic function of $x$ and $y$ cannot show the normality of them?

Comment: If $W$ is normally distributed and $V$ is not, then let $X = W - V$ and $Y = V$. Then $X + Y = W$ is normal but $Y = V$ is not.

Comment: "If $ax+by$ is normal for all $a$ and $b$ we can infer the normality of $x$ and $y$" is understating their conclusion. If $ax+by$ is normal for all $a$ and $b$ then in particular $1x+0y$ and $0x+1y$ are normal. It's harder to show that if $ax+by$ is normal for all $a$ and $b$, then $x,y$ are *jointly normal*.

Comment: Joint normality is also easy if we use characteristic functions.

Answer (score 1):

Compute for $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$, $E[\exp(i(sx+ty))]$. Note that this is the characteristic function of the normally distributed random variable $sx+ty$ (by assumption) evaluated at $1$.